# Apply Style to the letters according to the specifications

Tags: style

Apply Style to the letters A, B , C and D according to the specifications listed below. The number represents the font size and the color represents the font color. (Hint: Use Apply.)

Input:

```
{{"A",25,Red},{"B",30,Green},{"C",35,Blue},{"D",40,Brown}}
```

Expected Output:

[image]

After going through the Apply section (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), I fail to figure out how Apply can be applied for this problem.

More explanation that would help solve the problem appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand what you want. You say you want to change the style of the letters, then you show the expected output as something else. But if you mean you want to change the type of the letters, you can use `Style`

```
lis={{"A",25,Red},{"B",30,Green},{"C",35,Blue},{"D",40,Brown}}
Style[#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]]]&/@lis
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use short cut

```
Style @@@ lis
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this is not what you want, may be you can clarify.

Comment: The solution has worked. Might be there is also a way by Apply.

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions  when you do `Style["A",25,Red]` Mathematica is smart and knows that `25` is for font size and `Red` is for color and it applies them to the first argument which is "A" . If you want to make `{"A",25}` be red, you can do `Style[{"A", 25}, Red]`

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions you ask: `Might be there is also a way by Apply.` I am not sure what you mean. `f @@@ expr` is the same as `Apply[f,expr,{1}]` so the above answer is using `Apply`.

Comment: I was not aware f @@@ expr is the same as  Apply[f,expr,{1}].

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions You have asked several questions that are quizzes or exercises from Wolfram-U courses. This is not the forum for asking those questions. They should be asked on the Wolfram Community site post corresponding to the course. The point of a quiz or exercise is for you to solve it, not ask someone else to solve it for you.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I am sorry. Actually, I was trying to solve by myself while seeking help. Going forward, I will avoid this action.